# How to use ID Generator in SQL without Custom Function

Tags: ignite

Is there a way to use Ignite built-in ID Generator as described at https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/id-generator as-is without creating a custom SQL function to insert identity values for the primary key of table ?  For instance,

create table test_table (id int primary key, name char(100));

insert into test_table (id, name) values (Ignite built-in ID Generator, "abc");

insert into test_table (id, name) values (Ignite built-in ID Generator, "def");

insert into test_table (id, name) values (Ignite built-in ID Generator, "ghi");

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`RANDOM_UUID` function](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/random_uuid).

There is also an [request for enhancement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5625) to have auto-incremented fields.

If you want to use the Ignite's sequences as described on the page you've linked than yes, you have to create your own function.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav for referring to RANDOM_UUID function. Since that function generates 122 pseudo random bits, do you happen to know 

1. Is its performance per node and does not need synchronization with other nodes ?

2. Does it have any performance bottleneck for continuous mass inserts into the same table across multiple nodes ?

Comment: @Michael I can say with certainty that RANDOM_UUID function is completely local on each node and does not need to synchronize with others. As far as the performance impact, I think it should be as fast as standard Java UUID.randomUUID() method.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy for the answer and quick response.